# Is there a way to iterate the xml element in wso2 6.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Please someone could help. I have a set of data as csv(from excel multiple sheets i have formed csv)just i want to insert those data into multiple table depends the sheets of an excel.

please help me to sort out my issues.

I expected those csv in each iteration to form xml.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can build the XML from CSV data and iterate through the XML. Please find a sample config below. In this sample, it will pick the CSV files from the source directory and process.

Smooks Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list
 xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
 xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
  <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
  <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVReader</resource>
  <param name="fields">firstname,lastname,gender,age,country</param>
  <param name="rootElementName">people</param>
  <param name="recordElementName">person</param>
  </resource-config>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="CSVToXML"
    transports="https,http,vfs"
    statistics="disable"
    trace="disable"
    startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
    <inSequence>
        <smooks config-key="conf:/repository/smooks-config.xml">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
        </smooks>
        <!-- Here iterate through the XML -->
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="Operation">urn:placeOrder</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://<SOURCE_DIR></parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://<PROCESSED_FILES_DIR></parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://<FAILED_FILES_DIR></parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.csv</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

References:
1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/VFS+Transport
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Smooks+Mediator
3. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Iterate+Mediator

Comment: Hi, Thanks. First of all want to know without smooks its not possible? I want to do everything with one proxy. Kindly guide me to do

Comment: Hi Sumathi, this is still a single proxyservice. When adding the smooks mediator developer studio will ask you to create a configfile.